# How to alter a compound data type by modifying a returned private data member?

Tags: php, arrays, return-value, private

As [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php) mentions, PHP has eight primitive data types, namely scalars (boolean, integer, float, string), compound (array and object), and special (null and resource).

I would like to ask, since arrays are compound data types they should be returned by reference unlike the scalars which are copied when returned. So I should be able to alter the private data member so returned (in C++ this works). So why isn't the internal array data type altered (as per the comment in the code)?

NOTE: I know altering private data members in this way is bad coding, but I was wondering why it doesn't work.

[Here is a link to the code on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/S9YAV5).

```
<?php

class Foo {

  private $values;

  public function __construct() {

    $this->values = array();

  }

  public function addElement($key, $value) {

    $this->values[$key] = $value;

  }

  public function getValues() {

    return $this->values;

  }

}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->addElement("hello", "John Doe");
//WHY DOESN'T THE FOLLOWING LINE ALTER $foo->values ?
$foo->getValues()["goodbye"] = "Jane Doe";

var_dump($foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

1 . Return local var ? $values not exist .

```
public function getValues() {
    return $values;
}
```

2. return global var

   public function getValues() {

   ```
   return $this->values;
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) arrays are not returned by reference but copied when they are returned (I would be curious to know whether objects are copied when they are returned: I would be surprised if they were). Anyways, to return the array by reference use the `&` in front of the method name:

```
public function &getValues() {

  return $this->values;

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
object(Foo)#1 (1) {
  ["values":"Foo":private]=>
  array(2) {
    ["hello"]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
    ["goodbye"]=>
    string(8) "Jane Doe"
```

Here is the code on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/zpG5QX).